# Is there a way to detect dom 'stillness', when the dom inside an element has stopped changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

using MutationObserver it's pretty easy to call a function when the dom inside an element changes, like so:

```
var observeDOM = (function(){
    var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver,
        eventListenerSupported = window.addEventListener;

    return function(obj, callback){
        if( MutationObserver ){
            // define a new observer
            var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
                if( mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length )
                    callback();
            });
            // have the observer observe foo for changes in children
            obs.observe( obj, { childList:true, subtree:true });
        }
        else if( eventListenerSupported ){
            obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);
            obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
        }
    }
})();





observeDOM( $('#dom_element')[0] ,function(){ 
console.log('dom changed');
});
```

But I'd like it to do something when the dom inside '#dom_element' has *stopped* changing, or if there are no changes for a few miliseconds. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Use `setTimeout` and reset the timer when the DOM has updated (using `MutationObserver` or mutation events).

Comment: good thinking, I'd still be interested if mutationobserver had a built-in way of doing it though